# Share Picture to Picasa

Tags: picasa, share-menu

To begin with, I'm using a Google Apps account as a primary account, and am running 2.2 on a Samsung Captivate, non-rooted. I have Picasa Web Albums checked off under account Sync, and can see my web albums in the Gallery, however, I can't share pictures to Picasa, it's missing from the 'share to' list. Does anyone have any idea how I can set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. It's not that Picasa wasn't there as a share option, but rather it was not visible. There were too many items installed that offer this intent, and the Gallery application does not have a scrollable menu. This is apparently a known bug and it's been there for quite a while so it doesn't look like it's going to get fixed either. I now use a different application for sharing to Picasa.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some dedicated apps for this such as:

- [EasyShare](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.easyshare.android) - adds all sorts of sharing options
- [Picasa Tool Pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=larry.zou.colorfullife) - tool for managing your Picasa account from the phone.